# Possible to add migration using EF DbMigrator

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations, dbmigrator

Is it possible to add a migration file using DbMigrator in code instead of through the powershell commands?

Answer (score 0):

`DbMigrator` is class for running migrations. Classes for creating migration are in [`System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.design%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). `ToolingFacade` is called by powershell commands. Other classes represents low level API for creating migration code.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please expand on that a bit more? How would I add a migration using these files? Sorry, i'm very new to EF.

Comment: I have never tried it, I'm just pointing you to correct classes. You must find it yourselves. You can also check [EF source codes](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2773077f0a16#src%2fEntityFramework.PowerShell%2fMigrations%2fAddMigrationCommand.cs) to get better idea how it works.